# Ajax effect on console.log output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firebug

Let's look at the output of console.log. A click on the button changes the name if we use the function `changeName()`. But if we use the function `changeNameAjax()` (where `response.name = 'Ford Prefect'`), one click on the button doesn't change the name, only a second click does. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function(){

            //changeName();
            changeNameAjax();

            var box = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
            console.log(box);

            function changeName(){
                $('#box').html('<p>Ford Prefect</p>');
            }

            function changeNameAjax(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getName.php?jsoncallback=?',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#box').html('<p>' + response.name + '</p>');
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Update</button>
    <div id='box'>
        <p>Arthur Dent</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [AJAX is **asynchronous**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), meaning that `success` function doesn't run until later, when the response from the server comes back.  So this line:

```
$('#box').html('<p>' + response.name + '</p>');
```

Doesn't run until *after* you've called `console.log`, in fact if you click fast or the server is slow, you can click several times before the `success` function completes once.

Even if the response is *instantaneous* (local server for instance), since JavaScript is single threaded, that `success` still happens afterwards...to see this, just stick a `console.log('Success')` in your `success` function, then you'll get a good illustration of the order and when the callbacks execute.

Answer (score 0):

My 10 cents: It happens because you're declaring the changeNameAjax() function inside the click event. The first click will define the function, the second will execute it.

Comment: Not really, while each click will define a new changeNameAjax function inside the scope of the click function.
There is no way a second click can reach the changeNameAjax function defined in a previous click since each time the click function executes it will get a fresh scope.